# How to display hint of EditText AFTER a default value on the EditText? (Android Java)

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, textview, android-relativelayout

I would like the hint to display after a default value I put in the EditText.
For example, the contents of the EditText must look like:
`192.168.1.1 (Hint: First IP address)` - all inside the EditText, and when the user clicks it, it defaults to show only 192.168.1.1.

The EditText takes a string as input. I want the hint to just be there, but not count as the input string.

Please help.

Thanks
Regards

Comment: Try to use TextInputLayout instead. It has a better design and simpler to setup

Comment: Use (my answer)[http://stackoverflow.com/a/40988193/1803735] to rock

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I got your point. So you want a floating label when an edit text receive a focus. You just have to wrap your edit text inside TextInputLayout.

Here is my updated sample:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/input_layout_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_txt_id"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/str_reource_id"
            android:inputType="depends_on_your_use_case"/>

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: The EditText takes a string as input. I want the hint to just be there, along with the input, but not count as the input string. Do you now understand what I want to achieve?

Comment: Hi @Zac1 , you may now check my updated answer. Thanks :)

Comment: I already tried this. It only shows the label when there is focus on the EditText. I want the label to always be there.

Answer (score 1):

Define `ip_hint` and `ip` you want in resources then in your `onCreate`:

```
editText.setText(R.string.ip_hint);
editTxt.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
  @Override
  public void onFocusChange(final View view, final boolean hasFocus) {
    if (hasFocus)
      editTxt.setHint(R.string.ip);
    else if(editText.getText().equals(context.getResource(R.string.ip))
      editText.setText(R.string.ip_hint);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to achieve this task. Use hint as input string and append with input string.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the show, but you can also add a formatted string in your hint in onCreate,

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/foo"
        android:hint="@string/hint_foo"
        ...
```

where hint_foo is defined in string resource,

```
<string name="hint_foo">Foo: %1$s</string>
```

and then initialise with getString() in activity,

```
TextView hinter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.foo);
hinter.setHint(getString(R.string.hint_foo, ip_string));
```